# 'unresolved reference' error in R.java file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, r.java-file

I rename the package name from 'code.name.monkey.retromusic' to 'code.name.azplayer.bytetex' to upload the app in google play store and then i tried to build the app.It gave me the below error. R.java file is using the old import package name.How can i change the import package name in R.java file ?

[image]

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project

Comment: have you changed all of the file names not just the main one?

Comment: I unchecked the ‘compact middle packages’ and then refactor the two directory.(monkey to azplayer) & (retromusic to bytetex)

Comment: remove import line and re-import Gener file using Alt+Enter on all files.

Comment: Although It’s says it should not be edited,I tried and import package name is automatically replaced.